# How to make a complex query to count nested objects that match with a query on firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In a case of having the following structure:

**Collection of albums** where each album has a **collection of stickers** and each sticker has a type.

What is the best approach to count the total number of stickers I have by type, independent of which album the sticker is? I will need to fetch all documents or firestore allows this kind of complex queries?

Comment: Firestore doesn't offer any aggregation type queries.  If you want a count of documents without paying for a read of each document, you will have to maintain those counts yourself as the data changes over time.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't fully agree with this being a duplicate. The other question is about getting the count of a collection, which isn't exactly the same as getting the count of items based on a certain 'filter' (sticker type in this case)

Comment: @dumazy It turns out that both situations are considered queries in Firestore.  If you request all the documents in a collection, that is just a query without a filter.  Adding a filter doesn't really change the capabilities of the query.  In both cases, a count can only be obtained by executing the query and looking at the size of the result set.  So, for both cases, if you want a count without incurring the cost of reading all the documents, there needs to be a running tally. The difference is a matter of knowing which combinations of filters need to be counted.